# Code design - Should serializable classes have a duplicate class to protect access?

Tags: sqlite, serialization

I'm working on an app that uses XMLSerialization and SQLite. Both require public accessors. However, there are many instances where I want accessors to return conditional data or only have read access. With SQLite the accessors must both be public, so I can't even use protected.
What's the best way to handle this? Do I really need a secondary class that is basically a copy of the serializable class? With XML serialization I could possibly construct my own serialization process, but this is painful and probably worse than a shadow class.

Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of exploration it seems like this is an unfortunate YES. Really there should be the objects filled by SQLite queries and XML serialization in the Data Access layer. Then in the Business layer there should be a conversion of those objects to what is used by the app layer.

Hopefully this makes sense to others searching for the same.